# Is there any way I can retrieve twitter user's email Id (Objective-c)?

Tags: objective-c, email, twitter

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#6718

If twitter doesn't provide any API, then how does foursquare retrieve them?

- Foursquare has provision to list out the user's foursquare-friends who have registered with twitter.
- It also provides API which shows friends of users who commonly appear in 'foursquare friend's list' as well as 'twitter followers list' of the user.

In both the above cases comparison can be made only through email.
Please help.

Comment: Actually I do not think that they need the email for either functionality. I do not use foursquare, but from your description the first is a list of foursquare friends (and they know who they are by definition) that also have registered with twitter (and they know who has). The second seems to be a list of people that are both friends on foursquare and followers, which needs no email but can be done by comparing twitter names.

Comment: My friend has registered in both Twitter and Foursquare. The only field common in her profile is the email id. No other fields match. She comes in the 2nd list which i have mentioned above.

Comment: Did she in any way tell Foursquare that she is also registered with Twitter?

Comment: After she has registered with FourSquare, went to her profile, clicked on friends -> Add Friends -> opted Twitter. She was asked to login to Twitter and thus she did it. She has used her twitter username and password to login. That is the only means by which she has told foursquare that she has registered with twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way for you to get an e-mail from Twitter. Except, of course, by asking the person to give it.

What FourSquare does need no access to the e-mail. Matching is based on the Twitter name, not on the e-mail.

In the comments you say

> My friend has registered in both Twitter and Foursquare. The only field common in her profile is the email id. No other fields match. She comes in the 2nd list which i have mentioned above.

but then you admit

> After she has registered with FourSquare, went to her profile, clicked on friends -> Add Friends -> opted Twitter. She was asked to login to Twitter and thus she did it

This means that now FourSquare have access to her Twitter as well as your. Foursquare knows her Twitter id and your twitter id and can access Twitter (using Twitter API) to see who is following is following who. In other words when you say

> The only field common in her profile is the email id. No other fields match.

You are wrong. Once she connected her FourSquare profile with her Twitter, all data that is accessible via Twitter API is in fact (at least potentially) part of her Foursquare profile.

But she needed to explicitly connect the two profiles (which she did when she opted to add friends to her Foursquare profile using Twitter).

Comment: Another friend of mine registered on both foursquare and twitter using 2 different email id. Since she is a twitter friend of mine, foursquare suggested her as 'your twitter friends on Foursquare'. Hence you are right! Comparison is not made by emails. Many thanx for the reply.

Comment: Yup. It's not made by mail. It's made by twitter id. Once you connect an account to twitter, Foursquare knows your twitter id. It in fact is simpler to match your followers on twitter using their twitter id (which is what the list of followers immediately represent) than to ask twitter to convert each twitter id to an email (if it was possible) and then match the emails.

Comment: Without email Id, how does Instagram invite Twitter friends to join it? I am doing a similar application. Please suggest ideas. Where would the invitation be sent?

Comment: Explain how instagram works and maybe I can guess. But remember: no serious service will ever give you the e-mail of someone that subscribes to it. And in fact would never give you ANYTHING that the customer didn't explicitly tell it to give you. In many countries that would in fact be illegal too. If you want the e-mail of someone, you should ask that someone. There's no other (legal) way.

Comment: Instagram gives the following error when tapped on 'Find friends from Twitter friends' : Twitter no longer allows its users to access this information in Instagram via the Twitter API. We apologize for any inconvenience.

Comment: Has twitter recently stopped providing email id of user via API? Was it available earlier?

Comment: I have no idea what Instagram refers to with that message. But emails have never been available. No site will let you get an email unless the user has expressly told it to give it specifically to you. If ANY site were to let you get user emails it will be spam galore (and the site will be blocked for good by pretty much any internet provider in the world). Not even infamously privacy oblivious Facebook lets you get a user email without the user permission.

Comment: Yea. Thats what I am looking for. Similar to Facebook is there anyway you can retrieve Twitter user's email id via 'permission'?

Comment: Sure. Send a tweet asking for the mail. If the user agrees, he'll send you. Contrary to Facebook the guys at Twitter sort of understand privacy.

Comment: Nup. Thats not exactly what i mean.

Comment: **In Facebook** SDK not providing direct method for checking specific permissions but you can check if user granted permission to your application by checking permissions connection of user object in Graph API. GET https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions. Same can be achieved with FQL query on permissions table. SELECT email FROM permissions WHERE uid = me(). also,using the method [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions" andDelegate:self]; **Similar to the above is there anyway for twitter?**

Comment: As I told you, contrary to Facebook, Twitter understands privacy (sort of). There is NO way to get email from twitter API.